# How to claim a question in Nothing to Install?

Tags: support, status-completed

I asked a question yesterday right here, with just a name and email address (no login) and now that I registered for Nothing to Install I wish I could claim that question as mine. Am I able to do that or that question will be lost in limbo?

The question (in question) is [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/how-do-i-delete-my-bloglines-feeds) and the reason for wanting to claim it is so I can vote for the answer that helped me the most.

Answer (score 2):

I've merged your accounts together.